# Best practice - Setting a field without setters in a unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, mockito, getter-setter

Let's say you have the following class you would like to test:

```
public class SomeService {
  public String someMethod(SomeEntity someEntity) {
    return someEntity.getSomeProperty();
  }
}
```

The SomeEntity looks like this:

```
public class SomeEntity {
  private String someProperty;

  public getSomeProperty() {
    return this.someProperty;
  }
}
```

The assertion you would like to do can be the following:

```
String result = someService.someMethod(someEntity);

assertThat(result).isEqualTo("someValue");
```

How can you make this test work?

1) Add a setter for 'someProperty' in the SomeEntity class. I don't think this a good solution because you don't change production code to make your tests work.

2) Use ReflectionUtils to set the value of this field. Test would look like this:

```
 public class TestClass {
      private SomeService someService;

        @Test
          public void testSomeProperty() {
            SomeEntity someEntity = new SomeEntity();
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(someEntity, "someProperty", "someValue");

            String result = someService.someMethod(someEntity);

            assertThat(result).isEqualTo("someValue");
          }
}
```

3) You create an inner class in your test class that extends the SomeEntity class and adds the setter for this field. However, for this to work you will also need to change the SomeEntity class because the field should become 'protected' instead of 'private'. Test class might look like this:

```
public class TestClass {
  private SomeService someService;

  @Test
  public void testSomeProperty() {
   SomeEntityWithSetters someEntity = new SomeEntityTestWithSetters();
    someEntity.setSomeProperty("someValue");

    String result = someService.someMethod(someEntity);

    assertThat(result).isEqualTo("someValue");
  }


  public class SomeEntityWithSetters extends SomeEntity {
   public setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
     this.someProperty = someProperty;
   } 
  }
}
```

4) You use Mockito to mock SomeEntity. Seems fine if you only need to mock only one property in the class, but what if you need to mock like 10 properties are so. The test might look like this:

```
public class TestClass {
  private SomeService someService;

  @Test
  public void testSomeProperty() {
    SomeEntity someEntity = mock(SomeEntity.class);
    when(someEntity.getSomeProperty()).thenReturn("someValue");

    String result = someService.someMethod(someEntity);

    assertThat(result).isEqualTo("someValue");
  }
}
```

Comment: if class ClassToTest doesent have any constructor or setter .. how in prod they are populating the property .. again with reflection ?

Comment: and i guess with the junit you are actully testing SomeService method and not Classtotest. if this is a case you can mock ClasstoTest. and testing of ClasstoTest will be done separately and no mocking should be used there

Comment: In this case the property was set by Hibernate, it is a database Entity, Hibernate doesn't need setters to do this.

Comment: okay so in this case hibernate sets the field by reflection.

Comment: Yes it does, but that's not my concern in my test, I've renamend ClassToTest to SomeEntity because ClassToTest isn't actually the class I'm testing

Comment: ReflectionTestUtils - majestic!

Answer (score 16):

you can set the value using reflection. It doesn't need any change in production code.

ReflectionTestUtils.setField(YourClass.class, "fieldName", fieldValue);

Answer (score 2):

You can add a setter with default (package private) scope.

Comment: This would also change the production code, I don't want to do this if possible

Comment: Test driven development alwasy has big influence on the way you are coding. Often this improves the code. But sometimes it violates information hiding, to make information visible to tests. You cannot have perfect test coverage and perfect information hiding.

Answer (score 0):

With junit testing of SomeService.someMethod()

alternative 1. should not use this as no need to change entity for writing junit.

alternative 2. can be used.

alternative 3. again same a 3, no need to extend for just junit. how about when the class cannot be extended.

alternative 4. yes, a good option. mockito is being used for the same reason.

Comment: This is just a simple example, the someMethod() will probably do some more stuff but this is just an illustration of the issue

Comment: yes, true, and if someMethod makes calls to SomeEntity that should be mocked. in this way the someMethod will be tested. right ?

Comment: In my opinion it should indeed be mocked if the someEntity would be a dependency on this class, not if it is an object you are using. A service, repository, mapper, ... things like this need to be mocked indeed.

Comment: yes, infact if a service A is coupled with many services say (b,c,d) , then for testing of A one can mock all the dependencies. and the testing of BCD will be taken careof by their individual junits.

Answer (score 0):

What is the behavior / contract specific to `SomeService` that is testable?  Based upon your skeletal code, there really isn't any.  It will either throw a NPE on bad input, or return a String that may or may not be null, depending on Hibernate magic.  Not sure what you can actually *test*.

Answer (score 0):

I have been through this same dilemma many times before, a quick solution is to make the field you want to mock package protected, or provide a protected setter. Of course both will alter production code.

Alternatively, you can consider dependency injection framework, such as [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/). Below is an example they give:

```
@Module
class DripCoffeeModule {
  @Provides Heater provideHeater(Executor executor) {
    return new CpuHeater(executor);
  }
}
```

> This JUnit test overrides DripCoffeeModule's binding for Heater with a mock object from Mockito. The mock gets injected into the CoffeeMaker and also into the test.

```
public class CoffeeMakerTest {
  @Inject CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker;
  @Inject Heater heater;

  @Before public void setUp() {
    ObjectGraph.create(new TestModule()).inject(this);
  }

  @Module(
      includes = DripCoffeeModule.class,
      injects = CoffeeMakerTest.class,
      overrides = true
  )
  static class TestModule {
    @Provides @Singleton Heater provideHeater() {
      return Mockito.mock(Heater.class);
    }
  }

  @Test public void testHeaterIsTurnedOnAndThenOff() {
    Mockito.when(heater.isHot()).thenReturn(true);
    coffeeMaker.brew();
    Mockito.verify(heater, Mockito.times(1)).on();
    Mockito.verify(heater, Mockito.times(1)).off();
  }
}
```